# Run local vbscript from Outlook macro

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, outlook-2010

I would like to have a macro in Outlook 2010 that will run a vbscript on my local drive. Here's what I've tried.

```
Sub RUNvbscript()
Shell "Explorer.exe ""C:\rest of path""", 1
End Sub
```

That did not work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here: `Shell()`, the `ShellExecute()` API function, scripting host's `WShell.Run()`, etc. If you need to wait for your script to complete, however, `WShell.Run()` has a synchronous option, which makes it nice.

```
strPath = "c:\folder\myscript.vbs"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Run synchronously...
objShell.Run Chr(34) & strPath & Chr(34), 1, True

' Or, run asynchronously...
objShell.Run Chr(34) & strPath & Chr(34), 1, False
```

With the others, you'd need to use `WaitForSingleObject` or some other polling mechanism to determine when the script completes.